# Admob: Longer session or more downloads?

Tags: android, admob

I am using admob in my android app. I was wondering which one usually bring more revenue, more downloads or longer sessions?
I mean would you get more revenue for 2 downloads each playing a game for one minute or would you get more more for one download in which the game is played for 2 minutes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stay on the same page Ads will not auto refresh unless you have manually set in AdMob Settings page to auto refresh every 30 sec or you have handled it in code by putting some timer. Especially when watching a video or playing a game if users will be in same screen for around 5 min its better to manually set a refresh rate (That increases Ad Impression and decreases eCPM) or even better alternate between different ad networks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about refresh rate?  AdMob's general recommendation for refresh rate is 30 or 60 seconds.

Comment: Do I have control of refresh rate? I thought it is automatic